# Go: Unable to use jsonb in postgres database query

Tags: postgresql, go

I wrote a PG query (a function) which takes in an argument (jsonb).

This works when I run the query through `pgAdmin`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM f_get_profiles(
    '[{"role": 1, "experience": 1 }]'::jsonb, 
    array[2]::int[],
    array[1]::int[],
    10, -- limit 
    0   -- skip 
)
```

And this returns me 3 records from the DB.

But I am unable to do the same using go code:

```golang
    q := `
        SELECT * FROM f_get_profiles(
            $1::jsonb, $2::int[], $3::int[], $4, $5
        )
    `
    rows, pgErr := p.db.Query(q, f.Expertise, pq.Array(f.Languages), pq.Array(excluded), limit, skip)
    if pgErr != nil {
        return nil, logAndReturnError(pgErr, "Unable to get profiles using the filters")
    }
```

The `go` types of arguments passed are:

```
f.Expertise : json.RawMessage
f.Languages : pq.Int32Array
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong. I am not getting any array but this is returning empty result.

---

More details on how I am accessing the rows:

```
var profiles dto.ProfileSuggestions = dto.ProfileSuggestions{}
for rows.Next() {
    var p dto.ProfileSuggestionsNode
    err := rows.Scan(&p.UserId, &p.Username, &p.Photo, &p.About, &p.Languages, &p.Expertise)

    if err!=nil{
        return nil, logAndReturnError(err, "Unable to scan the profile")
    }
    profiles = append(profiles, p)  
}
```

#### values used from client request

```
2022/02/22 01:00:55 Excluded profiles found [1]
2022/02/22 01:00:55 Filtering languages  [2]
2022/02/22 01:00:55 Filtering expertise  [{"role": 1, "experience": 1}]
2022/02/22 01:00:55 Limit  10
2022/02/22 01:00:55 Skipping  0
```

Comment: Show the contents of *all* the fields passed to the `Query` method to prove that they are the exact same as in the pgAdmin query that has hardcoded values.

Comment: Also, what result do you get when you execute the query with hardcoded values through Go instead of pgAdmin?

Comment: Why do you believe the problem is with `jsonb`? Are you getting back an error that says that `jsonb` argument is not valid?

Comment: There is no error, the api responds with `[]`

Comment: @mkopriva added logs to prove that the values coming from client are same as the ones used in pgadmin

Comment: what about the second comment, have you tried that? what was the result of that?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I get 3 rows of users in return. Also, if I hardcode the same pgadmin query in go, it responds with same three rows. Something is wrong with how we are interacting with go code

Comment: Have you tried converting `json.RawMessage` to bytes or a string? e.g. `[]byte(f.Expertise)` or `string(f.Expertise)`?

Comment: Same issue when converted to []byte or string. Empty response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242244/discussion-between-karan-kumar-and-mkopriva).